Jira Xray Gadget - Can't figure out what gadget to use and what smart filters to make to display a counting of all statuses for certain Tests
This is my first time posting here.
I have Test Plan (ABC-1) that contains 300+ Tests. From those 300+ tests I am interested in only 22 of them(ABC-2 to ABC-23), that I run them daily for 10+ people (so a lot of them).
I created some filters that show only results for Pass or Fail, etc. (key in testTestExecutions("ABC-2","Pass) and so on)
What I can't figure out is how to display 22 Tests on the Y axis, and the Pass, Fail, etc statuses on the X axis ( with numbers + percentage from total)
EG:
Test                 Pass           Fail           Total
ABC-2               2(50%)         2(50%)         4(100%)
ABC-3
ABC-4
ABC-5
I only managed to show the statuses on the Y axis and issue count on the X axis for only one Test ( ABC-2 ) and I would prefer to use a single gadget instead of 22 or them.

Let's say that we have a Test Plan (e.g. CALC-229) with some tests, some of them already with some executions.

Then you want to use a gadget just showing some tests of that Test Plan. For that we need to use the Overall Test Results gadget, which shows the tests you want and how they are considering some scope (e.g., like the results obtained on a given Test Plan); it uses a pie chart as output.
You'll need first to create a filter to filter out just some of the tests in the Test Plan, based on some criteria (e.g., like the ones that are of Manual test type using issue in testPlanTests(CALC-229) AND "Test Type" = Manual)

We then use that filter on the configuration of the gadget, and we specify the Test Plan to be used to calculate the status of those tests.


If you need a bar kind of chart that shows Tests, grouped by their status, there is no such gadget out of the box. However, there's a Test Runs Summary gadget that provides the counts of Test Runs (not of Tests) grouped by the results reported for the test run; it's not exactly what you aim, but it's a bit related.
Other than that, you would need to use another Jira app, like eazyBI to accomplish that.
